# AES encryption returning different values on different machines

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

My AES encryption program is returning different encrypted values on different machines. Can anyone please help on finding out what needs to be done to ensure the same encrypted value is returned on any machine the program is run..

```
private static SecretKeySpec secret;
private static String seed;
private static String text;
private static String salt = "Salt123";
private static int pswdIterations = 65536;
private static int keySize = 256;

/**
 * 
 * @param mySeed
 */
public static void setSeed(String mySeed) {

    try {
        byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(mySeed.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
                pswdIterations, keySize);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String getEncryptedStringFor(String text) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedData));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getDecryptedStringFor(String text) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
        return (new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64
                .decodeBase64(text.getBytes("UTF-8")))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Some sample values

- seed : seed123
- text : #text!
- Encrypted value : RoVE3KsjzN0nNxCNsNpRPg==
- seed : seed!!
- text : #text123!
- Encrypted value :X6pfUKCVXXrAEyqKko/kFQ==

Comment: I feel like I saw exactly this source code already in a similary-named question: the problem is in the `cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(text.getBytes("UTF-8")))` line in the decrypting method, where `getBytes()` is superfluous.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin .Thanks for the reply. I did extract this code from various sources online , as I do not have any experience with encryption programs. Can you please elaborate on why that line of code is causing the issue ?

Comment: You can simply debug your code step-by-step and see what it returns and what is expected by the `decodeBase64()`.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin : I am using commons.codec-1.3.jar and it has decodeBase64() which takes a byte array as input. I believe the newer version has decodeBase64() which takes a string as the input. Is this what you were referring to? but in what way does it make the encrypted sting different in different machines ?

Comment: Add an example of password and input text and two (or more) different encryptions of it to the question.

Comment: What do these samples mean? Two different seeds and two different input texts - of course the results are different. Can you provide a sample when the same seed and same input result in two different encryptions? Provide a single seed, a single input and two different results. Otherwise there is no problem and this question is a waste of time.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin: unfortunately the issue occurred in production env and i am unable to replicate this in dev. I also do not have access to prod... In process of trying to replicate this is dev...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see in the code is the following line:

```
return (new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(text.getBytes("UTF-8")))));
```

Now it *looks* like this is actually returning a String after decoding with UTF-8. But it doesn't: it uses the platform default:

```
return (new String(
    cipher.doFinal(
        Base64.decodeBase64(
            text.getBytes("UTF-8")
        )
    )
));
```

Of course, the first `(` is superfluous anyway, so try this:

```
byte[] ciphertext = Base64.decodeBase64(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
return new String(plaintext, "UTF-8");
```

Note that you can also use `import static java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8` nowadays, which lets you do away with the exception as well. I wish they would do the same for StandardCiphers.AES_CBC_PKCS7PADDING :)

Comment: unfortunately the issue occurred in production env and i am unable to replicate this in dev. I also do not have access to prod... In process of trying to replicate this is dev...thanks for the help..